Check all elements of all subfields
How to check all elements in all subfields of a field without explicitly writing the names of the subfields?
For example, I have a document like this:
{
  "field": {
    "sub1": [{"set": "IC42", "code": 910}, {"set": "IC38", "code": 911}], 
    "sub2": [{"set": "BH90", "code": 912}, {"set": "BH70", "code": 913}]
  }
}

I want something like iterating through all subfields and checking whether any of them have any element with the "set" field with the text "IC42".
I don't want to use Mongodb Atlas search because it can produce unexpected results.
Edit 1:
although the previous answers work, however until the elements inside the subfields have multiple fields, for example:
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $ne: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: { $objectToArray: "$field" },
              cond: { $in: [{"set": "IC42"}, "$$this.v"] }
            }
          },
          []
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])

The above will work, but if I add more fields to the elements it no longer works..
What is the reason why elements with more fields make the query no longer work?

Please ask a new question and provide a link to this question for context if you have a new question. This will keep the current question focused.

For your question, the idea of the provided answer is to convert your field object into an array of k-v tuples like this. If you are adding more fields inside the field object, you need to query the relevant fields like this

The MongoDB does not have straight way to search from an object's sub-properties/fields without specifying them,
You can use aggregation operators in the match stage as below, there are multiple ways to do this using aggregation, but I don't recommend it for a scaled project, you can improve your schema with a key-value pair with an array of objects and it's called an attribute pattern as we are doing by $objectToArray operator as you can see in below query.

$objectToArray to convert the object to an array of objects in a key-value pair.
$filter to iterate the array of objects and check if the search/input value is in the provided array or not.
The $match stage checks the expression condition with the $ne operator that the result from the $filter operator should not equal an empty array [].

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $ne: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: { $objectToArray: "$field" },
              cond: { $in: ["IC42", "$$this.v"] }
            }
          },
          []
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])

Playground

You can change that aggregation pipeline into a find() by removing the outer $match part like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/NOLdXrbLUqO
